# Using letters instead of number for figures, e.g. "Figure A" instead of "Figure 1"

Tags: floats, letters

As the title says how can I change the figure text to use letters instead of numbers. I need to have "Figure A" instead of "Figure 1".

Comment: You need to redefine a corresponding counter. Hence, for figures add this to your preamble: `\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}`. See this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters) for more info about counters and other formats.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bergloef Np. It's better if you provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) we can compile. The answer may not necessarily be such trivial and may depend on details of you document, such as document class.

Comment: @Celdor Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @PeterWilson I post an answer but this is quite generic due to lack of more information from OP.

Answer (score 2):

Without specifics in the question, this is going to be a more generic answer.

First, I am going to assume the document class is `article`. Then this is the simplest solution. Just redefine `\thefigure` to change how the counter `figure` expands to its printed version. Expansion to capital letters is achieved by the command

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}
```

[Other formats](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters) are also possible, e.g. `\arabic` (default), `\alph`, `\roman`, `\Roman`, etc.

---

When a document class is either report or book, figures will gain chapter number by default as long as a chapter is used. Also, figures get reset every time a chapter counter is stepped. There is a number of options here:

1. Printed version is a simple counter redefined to expand to capital letters

```latex
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{figure}}
```

By default, the counter gets reset when chapter is stepped. To prevent LaTeX from doing so, the following macro needs to be issued

```
\countherwithout[\Alph]{figure}{chapter}
```

2. Original format is maintained: `Chapter.Figure` but the printed version of figure part expands to capital letters, s.a. `Figure 2.A: Caption.`

```latex
\counterwithin[\Alph]{figure}{chapter}
```

Again, the figure part gets reset every time chapter is stepped.

3. Finally, there is also an option to let counter continue regardless of chapter being used

```latex
\counterwithout[\Alph]{figure}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\Alph{figure}}
```

Again, the first macro prevents from resetting figures each time chapter is stepped. The other macro redefines the counter so that the original format `Chapter.Figure` is kept.

There's one note about redefinition. By default, figure counter numbers have some sort of intelligence. In reports and books, figures are that of a single format as long as a chapter is used. Then, figures get the extended format `Chapter.Figure`. Redefinition somehow removes that feature.

Hope this helps.